# Stream local webcam video in Kurento Crowd-detection project

Tags: kurento

I am working on [Kurneto-crowddetector](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-crowddetector) module. It takes video feed as input. I tried streaming my local webcamera through VLC streaming. Streaming is woorking perfectly in localnetwork but when I provide this url to Kurento module, it produces error at server side:

> 2017-03-21 06:21:01.796 ERROR 20843 --- [EventExec-e2-t8] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : Error received from Media serverInvalid Uri 0 INVALID_URI

2017-03-21 06:21:01.796 ERROR 20843 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : Error received from Media serverInvalid Uri 0 INVALID_URI

2017-03-21 06:21:02.181 ERROR 20843 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : Error received from Media serverInvalid Uri 0 INVALID_URI

2017-03-21 06:21:02.181 ERROR 20843 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : Timer added to create the player again

2017-03-21 06:21:02.183 ERROR 20843 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : Error received from Media serverInvalid Uri 0 INVALID_URI

2017-03-21 06:21:02.185 ERROR 20843 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : Error received from Media serverInvalid Uri 0 INVALID_URI

2017-03-21 06:21:02.187 ERROR 20843 --- [ventExec-e2-t10] org.kurento.demo.Pipeline                : **Error received from Media serverStream doesn't contain enough data. -> gsttypefindelement.c(983): gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin/GstTypeFindElement:typefindelement2363:**

Not sure about where things are going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very  basic check( you may have checked these), how about the url, is it a correct one? Any firewall blocking access to media server ?

Comment: URL are perfectly fine. No I am not behind any proxy, i am using open internet.

Comment: I even tried streaming android camera, still getting the same error.

Comment: does it work with your local setup ? I mean in LAN ?

Comment: oh yes !! perfectly ...

Comment: One doubt, the video feed that giving to kurento-crowddetector, should it have public ip or private ip will do ?